# Why is the drop down menu hiding behind jQuery button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui, menu

Why is the menu drop down hiding behind the jQuery button?

[image]

```
div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Code Please.. Also check the z-index of the button in the first place.. If its' > 9999 then obviously it will hide

Comment: Not sure about your html but you could try with `div.menu { z-index: 9999; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced this problem too. I found the cause and solution.

**Cause:** the button is rendered after the menu but it has been wrapped by some additional elements by `jquery-ui`, hence its `z-index` has been increased.

**Solution:** to overcome the problem, we can increase `z-index` of the menu (better way than decreasing `z-index` of many buttons). But please remember that

> "`z-index` only works on **positioned** elements (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`)"

That so we need to position our menu also. Here is my code:

```
<div style="position:relative;z-index:99"> MENU HERE </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Han.  That is the correct solution... Must be positioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this too

```
div.menu 
{

   z-index : 9999;
}
```

Seems like you are only setting the active li a z-index..
What happens to inactive one's

Comment: Check what the z-index for the button is??

Answer (score 1):

I have a jquery combobox plugin which will not show the full dropdown if the parent div is not big enough.  After much research and messing with the z-index and other things, I figured out that I needed to change the parent div overflow to "visible".  Maybe this will help someone if you're having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that your list has a z-index higher than your button like so

```
div.menu ul li {
 z-index:999;
}

.yourbutton {
 z-index: 1;
}
```

But paste in your html code for us to see.

Comment: The button: $('#button').button().css("z-index", "1");  Does not help.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code and we can see what's going on better.

Comment: $('#button').css("z-index", "1").button();  try this instead, I'm not sure how the .button() works but it might create a container which needs the z-index. That or try to find the parent container for the button and assign it the z-index

Comment: It's got to have something to do with the jQuery UI button!! If remove the .button(), the menu works just fine, covers the button like it's supposed to. :(

Comment: Try setting your "div.menu" and "div.menu ul" to z-index 999 too

Comment: Paste in your HTML code and javascript them so we can test it on jsfiddle.